# makeglossaries command always produce the same error

Tags: glossaries

when i try to create a glossary, the terminal command makeglossaries always produce me the following error:

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is illegal here in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\\@input{ <-- HERE (.+)\.aux}/ at /Library/TeX/texbin/makeglossaries line 634.
```

I never touched this file, the line 634 is the following `if` condition:

```
    # v1.9 added
        if (m/\\\@input{(.+)\.aux}/)
        {    
           &scan_aux($1);

           # v2.04 added
           # (Fix provided by Daniel Grund) 
           next;
        }
```

I use the following Latex version on OSX:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
Copyright 2015 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.6.17; using libpng 1.6.17
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
```

Can I do anything to resolve this problem, except re-installing Latex ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: this is a change in perl, it was deprecated but in the latest perl it is an error, just  change `\@input{(.+)\.aux}/` to `\@input\{(.+)\.aux\}/` and report to the makeglossaries author

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I add the same error farther in the file but using your solution everywhere did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a change in perl, it was deprecated but in the latest perl it is an error, just change `\@input{(.+)\.aux}/` to `\@input\{(.+)\.aux\}/` and report to the makeglossaries author

Comment: No need to report :-) Already fixed back in version v2.17.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I thought I remembered seeing something, but didn't have time to check:-)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot ah there is a dup, I searched for the error message and found lots of texdef and other perl programs here but missed that glossaries one

Comment: Just posted [a question on meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7464). I was sure there was an older dup, but the only other one I found didn't have an answer.